# A problem about stochastic process and wide sense stationarity

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider the process $\{X(t),t\geq0\}$ defined by:
$$X(t)=
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if t$\le$ Y}\\
0, &\text{if t$\gt$ Y}
\end{cases}$$
where $Y$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on the interval $(0,1)$.

> **1.** Compute, for $t\in[0,1]$, the first-order probability mass of $X$, $f(t,x)$.
>
> **2.** What is the first-order probability mass of $X$ for $t>1$?
>   *Could someone explain what is a first-order probability mass?*

Comment: I haven't heard this term, but my guess would be that they are referring to the one-dimensional distribution, i.e. the distribution of $X$ at just one time. This is as opposed to, say, the joint distribution of $X$ at some number of times considered together.

Comment: @Ian, Hi! Nice to see you again! I think your interpretation is right! But I don't know how to solve this problem, does it mean we just need to compute the probability of t<=Y, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I think they actually want the density but you can start from the CDF, which has $F_X(x)=0$ for $x<0$, $P(t>Y)$ for $0 \leq x<1$, and $F_X(x)=1$ for $x \geq 1$. $P(t>Y)$ should be easy to calculate.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about P(t>Y), I think that's what I don't know how to solve, I mean P(t>Y)=1-P(t$\le$Y)=1-t?

Comment: @Ian Is P{t>Y}=t?

Comment: Yes, $P(t>Y)=t$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: So actually, f(x,t)=t when 0≤x<1 and  0≤t≤1? sorry, with time in consideration, I'm a bit confused

Comment: What we just discussed may be summarized by saying $F_{X(t)}(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ t & 0 \leq x<1 \\ 1 & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$. They ask you for $f_{X(t)}(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so for f(x), when we take the derivative regarding x, t becomes t or 0? @Ian.

Comment: If we have the CDF right then $X(t)$ is discrete, so you want to get the PMF, which is easy enough.

Comment: Yes, you're right. so it should be like: $P_X(t)(X)=1-t$ when x=1, and equals to 0 otherwise?

Comment: Not quite: $F_{X(t)}$ has two jumps...

Comment: Could you format that? I'm so sorry about that, the note of my teacher haven't had any example for this... And I'm really bit confused of this k-order probability mass function concept... @Ian

Comment: For a single time it's just a regular old probability mass function. My point here is that for $t>0$ the CDF has a jump at $0$ and a jump at $1$; each one should give a contribution to the PMF.

Comment: $$P_X(t)(X)=\begin{cases}1-t &\text{if X=1} \\ t, &\text{if X=0}\end{cases}$$that's what I can figure out..

Comment: That's right, though I wouldn't use $X$ in both places.